# Appium: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: android, apk, appium, apple-m1, appium-android

```
Appium: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.school.assignment.rc' application.
```

Hello. This is for Android. I tried to run my tests but it's not proceeding the test in the login page. I can see the device when I try to run `adb devices` I get an error.

```
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.quipper.school.assignment.rc' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'com.quipper.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity' or 'com.quipper.school.assignment.rc.com.quipper.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.quipper.school.assignment.rc' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'com.quipper.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity' or 'com.quipper.school.assignment.rc.com.quipper.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
    at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
```

Not sure if this affects but here are the specs of my machine and the installed runner:

```
- Machine: MacOS Monterey, 16GB, M1 Pro Chip
- Android Studio (Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1)
- Emulator: Pixel 5 API 30, Android 11, arm64
- Appium-Server-GUI-1.22.3-4-mac
- PyCharm Community Edition
- Appium-Python-Client>=2.2.0
- behave>=1.2.6
- selenium>=4.2.0
```

Here are the capabilities of the emulator

```
    desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:platformVersion": "11.0",
        "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "appium:app": "/path/to/the/apk.apk",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        'apppackage': 'com.test.school.assignment.rc',
        'appactivity': 'com.test.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity'
    }

    # launch app
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
```